# How to remove large file from objects or from commit on github?

Tags: git, github

I have a big problem with github. In my repository theres is a large file ~600MB.
Github limit is 100MB for file.

My problem is how to remove this large file from the commit? I've physically removed it from directory and I commited once again but its still in commit. I don't know why. I've found this large file in `.git\objects\45` but when I delete it `git push` doesn't work.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`git push` pushes the complete history, not just the last commit. It's normal that `git rm big-file; git commit -a; git push` still pushes the content of the big file, because it appears in history, even though not in the latest version. Don't delete manually files in `.git/objects`, it's the internal database of Git, you're going to make it inconsistent.

You need to edit the history to remove any track of the big file. `git commit --amend` can help, but there are also specialized tools for this like [BFG repo cleaner](https://rtyley.github.io/bfg-repo-cleaner/).